# Campaign Events API Endpoint

Tags: c#, restsharp, mailgun

I'm trying to get all events for a specific campaign since a particular `datetime`.

The API is returning the same results for any `begin` value I specify (past or future) and I've sent 2000+ emails (with open and click tracking enabled) over the past few days.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/MYDOMAIN.com";
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "MYKEY");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "campaigns/MYCAMPAIGN/events";
request.AddParameter("begin", "Mon, 10 Feb 2014 23:59:00 -0000");
request.AddParameter("ascending", "yes");
return client.Execute(request).Content
```

This returns the same exact results in the same descending order no matter which `datetime` I specify for `begin`. (It seems to be returning to be the most recent events.)

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

I would like to specify a `datetime` and get the x oldest events that occured on or after the specified `datetime` in ascending order (oldest first, newest last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Events API does not appear to support filtering by CampaignId and the Campaign API does not appear to support filtering by date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, can you use tags as filter fields and put there the date information

https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-events.html#filter-field